# Update Replace query is replacing every entry in the column?

Tags: sql

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong, but it is Monday so this is expected.  I am trying to process some data in a table.  Occasionally, one of the columns will contain a question mark.  I would like to replace all question marks to NULL.

This is my query, but it seems to just replace every single entry.

```
Update Table
set [Hours] = REPLACE([Hours], '?', NULL)
```

I have also tried

```
Update Table
set [Hours] = REPLACE([Hours], CHAR(63), NULL)
```

I am pretty confident I am missing the simplest mistake.  I just can't see it for some reason.

Comment: `Update Table
set [Hours] = REPLACE([Hours], '?','')`

Comment: It's still replacing every single entry.  None of them have '?' in them either.

Comment: you need add a where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite this query to not use a `REPLACE`

```
UPDATE Table SET [Hours] = NULL WHERE [Hours] = '?'
```

EDIT: As for the reason your original query didn't work, as AlexK and roryap say, [The docs for `REPLACE` say that:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

> Returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL.

You can test this by performing a simple replace, such as:

```
SELECT REPLACE('asdf', '?', NULL)
```

This will return null, even though `?` isn't in the search string.

Comment: Ok, this worked, but why did the previous way not work?  I feel like Replace should replace every entry that contains the second argument with the third argument.

Comment: Because the docs for replace state: *Returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL*

Comment: @LeythG -- See my answer.  `REPLACE` returns `NULL` if any of the parameters is `NULL`.

Comment: Ok I understand, so in this case:  set [Hours] = REPLACE([Hours], '?', '') the '' is considered null?

Comment: @LeythG in that case no, it isn't `NULL`, `''` would be considered exactly what it is - an empty string. If you _really_ want to use `REPLACE`, you could use your example above and then do an update exactly like my example but searching for `''` instead of `'?'`, but at that point you're performing 2 queries when my example works fine in a single query.

Comment: Oh, I will definitely use yours.  I just wanted to make sure I understand the differences along the way.  Thank you for your help and everyone else's.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `where` clause;

```
Update Table set [Hours] = NULL
   where [Hours] like '%?%'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx, `REPLACE`

> Returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL.

Use the `WHERE` clause, as suggested by the other answers:

```
UPDATE Table SET [Hours] = NULL WHERE [Hours] = '?'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

```
update table set Hours = null where Hours='?'
```